# How to color table in Grafana based on individual column values?

Tags: grafana

I have a grafana table which shows max, min, avg and std.dev. When I set the `color scheme`, the color map range is based on whole table values. However, I want the range based on individual columns. How to do this?

For example in below pic, I want min with 16.3 to show in red,
[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can do that with the Overrides panel. Create a new override, match the field by the name of the column and add a Treshold, that is all!

Comment: Although the answer is not very specific it guides you in the right direction if you're willing to experiment a little. +1